# Blazor issue when binding to a select element

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I am using `@bind-value` to bind the selected value of a select element to a variable in Blazor. It works fine, if I physically click the drop down and select a value. However, if I select a value in the drop down through Javascript, Blazor doesn't seem to detect the change. I wrote a very simple program to demonstrate.

Here is my component `.cshtml` code:

```
@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime

<select id="my-select-box" @bind-value="MyValue" @bind-value:event="onchange">
    <option value="0">-- Select Something --</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>

<br />

@if (MyValue == "0") {
    <div>Select an option</div>
} else {
    <div>You chose @MyValue</div>
}

<div style="margin-top: 20px">
    <button @onclick="@(() => SelectOptionThroughJs("1"))">Select Option 1</button>
    <button @onclick="@(() => SelectOptionThroughJs("2"))">Select Option 2</button>
    <button @onclick="@(() => SelectOptionThroughJs("3"))">Select Option 3</button>
</div>

@code {
    public string MyValue {get;set;} = "0";

    public async Task SelectOptionThroughJs(string option)
    {
        await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("helperFunctions.selectOption", option);
    }
}
```

And here is my javascript code:

```
window.helperFunctions = {
    selectOption: function(op) {
        var selectBoxElement = document.getElementById("my-select-box");

        selectBoxElement.value = op;
    }
}
```

I also created a [fiddle to demonstrate](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/c1va0dkl).

If you physically select an item from the drop down, you'll see it works just fine. However, if you click one of the 3 buttons, you'll see the value does change in the drop down, but Blazor does not seem to realize the value changed.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Blazor does not seem to realize the value changed

Exactly...
Your select element is bound to the property MyValue, and whenever the current component is rendered, the select element gets its value from the property. Changing the selection through JS Interop has no effect on the property MyValue. The easiest was to solve this issue is to set the value of MyValue to the parameter you pass to the JS function, like this:

```
MyValue  = option;
```

but then calling the JS function becomes superfluous... Perhaps, you can tell us what you're trying to achieve.

A point to remember, you shouldn't use JS for such tasks that interfere with the rendering system of Blazor.

Comment: The example I posted here was just to demonstrate. What I actually did was built an autocomplete text box using [this article](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp). It works great, however, the issue is this. When I start to type something, such as "aus", and then select something, such as "Austria" from the list, Blazor sets the variable to "aus" instead of "Austria". I am sure the issue is exactly as you described. Because the textbox is being set through Javascript and Blazor doesn't realize the value changed.

Comment: You shouldn't code like this. Implement autocomplete purely in C£, without using JS. You may use ling, and other means such as Task.Delay to delay the search as the user type, etc. Here's a link to a question I've ask about a similar issue from which you can gain some clues on how to do that: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/15955 . As far as I remember, there are some solutions created by the community, which you can look for. Currently, Blazor cannot provide the capabilities Angualr provides in this respect, but I believe the some of the solutions provided by the community aregood

Comment: Thanks for your help and input.

Comment: @Icemanind, the following link is to a sample app created by Steve Sanderson: https://github.com/SteveSandersonMS/CarChecker. It contains a component named Autocomplete in the Shared folder. I did not review the code or try it, but I'm sure you should find it very useful.